# C# Windows Service memory exception

Tags: c#, windows, memory, memory-management, service

The Windows Service is a 32-bit implementation, due of the use of two referenced 32-bit libraries; Lotus Domino Objects and IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries.

Within the Windows Service I am parsing logfiles and keep their data in datatables in memory for comparing the data. A timer is used for sending emails.

The service was runnning several months without any problems.

Actually ~6GB of installed 8GB memory of the server are always in use and my service isn't running properly anymore, throwing the following exceptions:

"Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt." -> thrown by the the sending method

"System.OutOfMemoryException" -> thrown by the timer_elapsed method

When the service was running properly only about ~2GB of memory were always in use.

Does the service tries to allocate memory that is not adressable because over 70% of memory is always in use?

How does a 32-bit application behave on a 64-bit system when the memory area 0x00000000 - 0xffffffff is still in use? Physically it can not adress > 0xffffffff

---

I am using datatables as follows and write some data to the datatables:

```
private DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
private DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
private DataTable dt3 = new DataTable();
private DataTable dt4 = new DataTable();
private DataTable dt5 = new DataTable();
private DataTable dt6 = new DataTable();
dt1 = getDB2Data(); 
dt2 = ParseLogFile(path, time); 
dt3 = CompareDataTables(dt1, dt2);
dt4 = getDB2Data(); 
dt5 = ParseLogFile(path, time); 
dt6 = CompareDataTables(dt4, dt5);
```

---

```
I disposed all datatables after use:

dt1.Dispose();
dt2.Dispose();
dt3.Dispose(); 
dt4.Dispose();
dt5.Dispose();
dt6.Dispose();
```

Comment: "I am parsing logfiles and keep their data in datatables in memory for comparing the data" - How are you doing this?

Comment: Each process has its own address space, with it's own, attendant, range of *virtual* addresses. There's nothing that prevents a 32-bit process from having physical pages located above the 4GB boundary mapped into its address space. So your assertion that it "physically can not address > 0xffffffff" is incorrect.

Comment: Are you disposing of any unused tables? Do you free any data after processing it?

Comment: "So your assertion that it 'physically can not address > 0xffffffff' is incorrect" - yes, you are right!

Comment: "Are you disposing of any unused tables? Do you free any data after processing it?" - I will check all code again.

Comment: sry for my late response.
I checked all unused resources that they are released properly.

Comment: sry for my late response.
I checked all unused resources that they are released properly.
The problem was the notessession object allocation, it 's not allowed to dispose the notessession object or set to null and allocate again -> that caused the error. 
Can be read somewhere on the IBM website, not easy to find :-) 
Bad IBM implementation :-(